# Bonding connections to increase upload speed

Tags: networking, router, mikrotik-routeros, plex, bonding

I have a plex media server stuck on a 3 mb UP vDSL line. I thought about bonding this WAN with a different ISP LTE router 10+ mbps UP, though not steady. (It can drop to below 5 sometimes)

I found that Mikrotik's Hex router can do that with it's MPLS capability, but I'm still suspecious. I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere. Also Load balancing won't work as it's 1 connection/stream.

1. can this be done essentially?
2. Don't I need some software/hardware on the client's end? How will the media player (which sends its' requests to the DSL IP) accept packets sent from the LTE IP?

Thanks all for help.

Comment: Is just the LTE connection not enough? Also note that many "bonding" mechanisms are still intentionally limited to using only one link per stream, to avoid TCP reordering.

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not reliable enough as said above, also it's capped, but thanks for taking interest.

Comment: Which mechanisms? The whole point of why I need bonding is because I need 2+ links per stream, otherwise I'd get a multi wan router with load balancing capability or a software like speedify.

Comment: Note that any forming of bonding requires support on *both* sides of the bonded connection, because of how TCP and UDP work (no multihoming). So if your one endpoint is your home router, what's the other endpoint? "Any client" won't work.

Comment: I control/have access to both ends of the connection so no problem in this regard. do you know what sort of support I need on the receiving end?

Answer (score 0):

> Also Load balancing won't work as it's 1 connection/stream.

That rules out several bonding methods as well, as they (intentionally) pick the outgoing link per-connection.

AFAIK, spreading a single connection across 2 links (especially of very different speeds) would result in packets getting massively reordered by the time they reach the client – I suspect it would be beyond TCP's capabilities.

It seems that [Multi-link PPP](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:MLPPP_over_single_and_multiple_links) would work for you.

> How will the media player which's connected to the DSL IP accept packets sent from the LTE IP??

It won't. (Some protocols allow roaming, but not in your case.)

To make this work without the ISPs' cooperation, you would need to find another way to share a *single* IP address between connections. For example, you could:

1. rent a server (a cheap VPS), which comes with its own IP address;
2. set up two VPN connections between your router and that server (one via DSL, another via LTE);
3. on your router, bond the two VPN connections (using ML-PPP or whatever);
4. configure port-forwarding from the server to Plex (via the VPN);
5. then use the *server's* IP address in all clients.

(But then you could just rent a server to run Plex, and avoid all this trouble...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the link. Very informative.
I see your point about TCP reordering with different speeds, but let's assume I can handle it through MLPPP or other method (Not sure if MLPPP works with 2 different ISPs). isn't there anyway to configure both incoming connections (from dsl and lte) as if they were 1 on the client side? I control both ends of the connection.

Comment: Isn't half of my post about how to do that?

Comment: I think it can be done in a simpler way without the use of a vps in vpn, which will increase latency and reduce much needed speed. Don't get me wrong afaik your suggestion will work, but will defeat the purpose of better streaming experience by my estimates. (operation succeeded patient died kind of situation)  By client side I meant directly on the media player OS. I might be wrong but I'll send you a message if I find a better way. Thanks again grawity